# How to determine that this series is conditionally convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \frac{\sin\pi x}{x^p+1} \,\mathrm d x, \qquad 0<p\leq 1
$$

The reference answer only additionally hints to use the *first mean value theorem for definite integrals*.

According to the hint, my thoughts are as follows,
$$
\begin{align*}&
\int_n^{n+1} \frac{\sin\pi x}{x^p+1} \,\mathrm d x\\
<&
\left|\sin\bigl( (n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi \bigr)\right|\,
\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x^p+1} \,\mathrm d x\\
=&
\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x^p+1} \,\mathrm d x\\
<&
\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x^p} \,\mathrm d x
=\left.\frac{x^{1 - p}}{1 - p}\right\vert_n^{n+1}\\
=&
\frac{{(n + 1)}^{1 - p} - n^{1 - p}}{1 - p}
\end{align*}
$$

I know I'm obviously on the wrong path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\sin(\pi x)$ doesn't change its sign on the interval $[n,n+1]$ since its zeros are $x=k\in\mathbb{Z}$. By the mean value theorem there's a $c_n\in[n,n+1]$ such that
$$\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x^p+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{(c_n)^p+1}\int_n^{n+1}\sin(\pi x)\,dx $$
For the last integral, we have
$$\int_n^{n+1}\sin(\pi x)\,dx
=-\frac{1}{\pi}\cos(\pi x)\Bigg\vert_n^{n+1}\\
=-\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\cos((n+1)\pi)-\cos(n\pi)\right)=\frac{2\cdot(-1)^n}{\pi}$$
so you have to establish the convergence of
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(c_n)^p+1} $$
which follows from the alternating series test, and the divergence of
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(c_n)^p+1} $$
which follows from a comparison with the divergent series $\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^p+1}=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p+1} $.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!